# How to find subdomain from a url

Tags: php, .htaccess

`URL = http://company.website.com/pages/users/add/`

How do i find the subdomain from this via PHP

Such that `$subdomain = 'company'`

And `$url = '/pages/users/add/'`

Comment: Even if you're completely unaware that PHP has functions to parse URLs, and unwilling to look in the PHP manual to find it, you should know that virtually every programming language has ways to search for characters in a string and to take substrings of a string, which is all you need to parse a URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at PHP's [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).  This will give you the basic components of the URL which will make it easier to parse out the rest of your requirements (the subdomain)

```
$url        = 'http://company.website.com/pages/users/add/';
$url_parsed = parse_url($url);
$path       = $url_parsed['path']; // "pages/users/add/"
```

And then a simple regex* to parse `$url_parsed['host']` for subdomains:

```
$subdomain = preg_match("/(?:(.+)\.)?[^\.]+\.[^\.]+/i", $url_parsed['host'); 
// yields array("company.website.com", "company")
```

* I tested the regex in JavaScript, so you may need to tweak it a little.

Answer (score 1):

Or to avoid the regex:

```
$sections = explode('.', $url_parsed["host"]);
$subdomain = $sections[0];
```