# How to find all subdomain for a particular given domain

Tags: web-scraping, dns

So I have a  domain name let's say `example.com`, so is it possible to find all the sub-domains like `a.example.com`, `b.example.com`, etc.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a list of all subdomains of a domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131989/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-subdomains-of-a-domain)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find subdomain from a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883687/how-to-find-subdomain-from-a-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use command like:

```
dig example.com ALL
```

or

```
host -l example.com
```

But be aware you will get result only if machine where you run this have permission to do  zone transfers for this domain. Otherwise you will see nothing.

Comment: No. Double No. First `ALL` is not `AXFR` so your example and your text disagree. `AXFR` is almost always filtered anyway and if you use it you should contact the authoritative nameserfvers not a random one. As for `ALL` which is `ANY` in fact, it is 1) deprecated 2) not doing what people think it does, as it gives the content of the cache of the resolver you query, which is certainly not all records.